Check for Proxy Auth errors in Golang
I have a wss client that tries to make wss connection via a proxy. How can I specifically check for proxy connections errors, proxy authorization errors?
    conn, _, err := websocket.Dial(ctx, "wss://localhost:8080/ws", opts)
    if err != nil {

        var netErr *net.OpError
        switch {
        case errors.As(err, &netErr) && netErr.Op == "proxyconnect":
            log.Fatal("Proxy connect TCP error: ", netErr)
        // TODO: check if the error is due to proxy auth
        default: // other errors
            log.Fatal("Failed to connect to WebSocket server: ", err)
        }
    }
    ...

With errors.As(err, &netErr) && netErr.Op == "proxyconnect", I can check for proxy connect errors like when URL was incorrect, or Proxy address was not resolvable etc.
2024/06/27 06:38:18 Proxy connect TCP error: proxyconnect tcp: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8887: connect: connection refused
exit status 1

Error trace for proxyconnect:
error(*fmt.wrapError) *{msg: "failed to WebSocket dial: failed to send handshake request: Get \"https://localhost:8080/ws\": proxyconnect tcp: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8887: connect: connection refused", err: error(*fmt.wrapError) *{msg: "failed to send handshake request: Get \"https://localhost:8080/ws\": proxyconnect tcp: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8887: connect: connection refused", err: error(*net/url.Error) ...}}
error(*fmt.wrapError) *{msg: "failed to send handshake request: Get \"https://localhost:8080/ws\": proxyconnect tcp: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8887: connect: connection refused", err: error(*net/url.Error) *{Op: "Get", URL: "https://localhost:8080/ws", Err: error(*net.OpError) ...}}
error(*net/url.Error) *{Op: "Get", URL: "https://localhost:8080/ws", Err: error(*net.OpError) *{Op: "proxyconnect", Net: "tcp", Source: net.Addr nil, Addr: net.Addr nil, Err: error(*net.OpError) ...}}
error(*net.OpError) *{Op: "proxyconnect", Net: "tcp", Source: net.Addr nil, Addr: net.Addr nil, Err: error(*net.OpError) *{Op: "dial", Net: "tcp", Source: net.Addr nil, Addr: net.Addr(*net.TCPAddr) ..., Err: error(*os.SyscallError) ...}}
error(*net.OpError) *{Op: "dial", Net: "tcp", Source: net.Addr nil, Addr: net.Addr(*net.TCPAddr) *{IP: net.IP len: 16, cap: 16, [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,255,255,127,0,0,1], Port: 8887, Zone: ""}, Err: error(*os.SyscallError) *{Syscall: "connect", Err: error(syscall.Errno) *(*error)(0xc000066110)}}

But how can I get Proxy Auth Errors?
2024/06/26 17:48:07 Failed to connect to WebSocket server: failed to WebSocket dial: failed to send handshake request: Get "https://localhost:8080/ws": Unauthorized

I found this Error trace when I was using Tiny Proxy for testing:
error(*fmt.wrapError) *{msg: "failed to WebSocket dial: failed to send handshake request: Get \"https://localhost:8080/ws\": Unauthorized", err: error(*fmt.wrapError) *{msg: "failed to send handshake request: Get \"https://localhost:8080/ws\": Unauthorized", err: error(*net/url.Error) ...}}
error(*fmt.wrapError) *{msg: "failed to send handshake request: Get \"https://localhost:8080/ws\": Unauthorized", err: error(*net/url.Error) *{Op: "Get", URL: "https://localhost:8080/ws", Err: error(*errors.errorString) ...}}
error(*net/url.Error) *{Op: "Get", URL: "https://localhost:8080/ws", Err: error(*errors.errorString) *{s: "Unauthorized"}}
error(*errors.errorString) *{s: "Unauthorized"}

When I used Squid Proxy, I got a different error string.
Proxy Authentication required

So, how can I identify the Proxy Auth errors especially when error strings are different?
